# Как спроектировать базу данных MySQL для хранения данных из Чек-листов Аудитов

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование

Всем привет,

Создаю аппликацию для хранения данных по аудитам. Необходима грамотная подсказка как спроектировать базу данных SQL для хранения данных из чек-листов.

1. Чек-листы (шаблоны) могут быть разными по наполнению (разный список вопросов, вес и т.п.)
2. Есть очередность вопросов, вес по каждому и группировка
3. Чек-лист содержит аудируемый участок, дату проведения, результат и имя аудитора

Пытаюсь понять как сделать правильно, чтобы потом не переделывать несколько раз. Буду признателен за помощь! Спасибо большое заранее.

Прикрепил пример аудит листа.

[image: Пример Чек-листа Аудита]

Comment: Также вопрос: Лучше все это хранить отдельными записями в таблицах или хранить чек-лист как объект с элементами (вопрос, оценка и т.п.)?

Comment: А возможен только mysql??? если данные сильно будут разниться, то не проще ли хранить их в формате JSON в том же postgresql??? Будет большая гибкость в составлении их.

Comment: Это я не изучал еще